# Cannot open database “poststore.mdf” requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I get this message when I am trying to open the DB connetcion on server explorer, and no idea how to fix it. I am using the code first approach.
I know this question might look like a duplicate, but I tried all other similar questions, and I still have this problem.

Currently I have this project not on my original Admin account, but I've granted all the admin privileges to this account.

My connection string looks like this :

```
<connectionStrings> 
    <add name="DBConnection" 
         connectionString="data source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=poststore.mdf;Integrated Security=True;"   
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/> 
</connectionStrings>`
```

Exact error :

> Cannot open database "poststore.mdf" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'DESKTOP-ET4IF9Q\internship'.

And here is my context class located in the models folder :

```
namespace class_project.Models
{
    public class ClassAppContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }

        public ClassAppContext() : base("ClassAppDbContext")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<ClassAppContext>());
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove(new PluralizingTableNameConvention());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.AddFromAssembly(typeof(PostMap).Assembly);
        }
    }

    public class PostMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Post>
    {
        public PostMap()
        {
            ToTable("Post");
            HasKey(x => x.PostId)
                .Property(x => x.PostId)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

            Property(x => x.Title)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasColumnType("nvarchar")
                .HasMaxLength(250);

            Property(x => x.Content)
                .HasColumnType("nvarchar")
                .HasMaxLength(500);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the exact error and put it in your question... not in your title

Comment: I edited my question, see the edit

Comment: why this? ```base("ClassAppDbContext")```? That string is connection string name from config file (or connection string itself). Have you tried ```base("DBConnection")``` ? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.dbcontext(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.DbContext.

Comment: obviously, you current user has no rights to connect to DB. You have to provide proper credentials

Comment: _"i've granted all the admin privilegies to this account._" - but have you added your account on the DB server? What roles did you add it to?

Comment: @stuartd No, I haven't. Should i do this through VS ? :/

Comment: You can add a login via the Sql Server Explorer window, but all that gets you is the script. If you want a GUI, you're better off creating it via Sql Server Management Studio.

Comment: There is something wrong with your connection string, the initial catalog should be a database name, not a file name

Comment: @ErikEJ it can be file name https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj653752(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Not the "Initial Catalog" key...

Comment: @ErikEJ ah, true. Doesn't note that.